# Docker - Unable to run sqllite3 directory with knex.js using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, sqlite, npm

I'm trying to run Docker with node: 14.17.5-alpine using sqllite3 directory version 5.0.2

Everything works perfectly through my computer (WIN10) but as soon as I try to transfer it to Linux Docker I get an error:

According to what is written I need to install sqlite3 but the directory is in the package.json file

I read online to see what can be done about it but did not find an unequivocal answer

Does anyone encounter the issue and know how to solve the file problem found in the path "/app/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/napi-v3-linux-x64/node_sqlite3.node"

```
> my-project@1.0.0 start /app
> node app.js

Knex: run
$ npm install sqlite3 --save
Cannot find module '/app/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/napi-v3-linux-x64/node_sqlite3.node'
Require stack:
- /app/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/sqlite3-binding.js
- /app/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/sqlite3.js
- /app/node_modules/knex/lib/dialects/sqlite3/index.js
- /app/node_modules/knex/lib/knex-builder/internal/config-resolver.js
- /app/node_modules/knex/lib/knex-builder/Knex.js
- /app/node_modules/knex/lib/index.js
- /app/node_modules/knex/knex.js
- /app/config/database.js
- /app/app.js
Error: Cannot find module '/app/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/napi-v3-linux-x64/node_sqlite3.node'
Require stack:
- /app/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/sqlite3-binding.js
- /app/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/sqlite3.js
- /app/node_modules/knex/lib/dialects/sqlite3/index.js

/app/node_modules/knex/lib/client.js:182
      throw new Error(`${message}\n${e.message}`);
      ^

Error: Knex: run
$ npm install sqlite3 --save
Cannot find module '/app/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/napi-v3-linux-x64/node_sqlite3.node'
Require stack:
- /app/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/sqlite3-binding.js
- /app/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/sqlite3.js
- /app/node_modules/knex/lib/dialects/sqlite3/index.js
- /app/node_modules/knex/lib/knex-builder/internal/config-resolver.js
- /app/node_modules/knex/lib/knex-builder/Knex.js
- /app/node_modules/knex/lib/index.js
- /app/node_modules/knex/knex.js
- /app/config/database.js
- /app/app.js
    at Client_SQLite3.initializeDriver (/app/node_modules/knex/lib/client.js:182:13)
    at new Client (/app/node_modules/knex/lib/client.js:71:12)
    at new Client_SQLite3 (/app/node_modules/knex/lib/dialects/sqlite3/index.js:20:5)
    at knex (/app/node_modules/knex/lib/knex-builder/Knex.js:12:28)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/app/config/database.js:3:21)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:759:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:770:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:628:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:555:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:666:19)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! ms-node-passport@1.0.0 start: `node app.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the ms-node-passport@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-08-22T02_47_27_119Z-debug.log

- /app/node_modules/knex/lib/knex-builder/internal/config-resolver.js
- /app/node_modules/knex/lib/knex-builder/Knex.js
- /app/node_modules/knex/lib/index.js
- /app/node_modules/knex/knex.js
- /app/config/database.js
- /app/app.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:610:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:526:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:666:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:16:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/sqlite3-binding.js:4:15)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:759:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:770:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:628:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:555:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:666:19)
```

Comment: Can you edit the question to include a [mcve], not just the error message?  Did you copy the `node_modules` tree from the Windows system too, or just did a clean checkout from source control?  You mention Docker, are you incorrectly overwriting the source code in the image with a bind mount?

Comment: @DavidMaze Hey, thanks for the answer, regarding your question it turns out I used a mount that overwrote all the information my Docker created
Thanks for the response! you helped me alot